# 4 equispaced elements, bunched on first load in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfusm

but every now and again (and only in Chrome and first load) the 4 boxes are bunched to the left, a refresh fixes the issue and gives equispaced boxes with first left aligned and last right aligned.

Anyone have an idea how to stop this first load bunching?

I have tried adding a `&nbsp;` after each `aside` but doesn't help

**info**:

Chrome is version 31.x, unable to replicate in IE 7-11 and FF.

There will always be 4 boxes.

Comment: Chrome 31.x here, on first load the four boxes where correctly displayed.

Comment: Seems to not be first load, but on random refreshes they bunch up. two separate PCs on Win 7 using Chrome's latest. difficult to replicate as it appears to be very hit and miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the elements from inline-block to block is some css that was inadvertently having some impact. lame.